# How can I use data from a string in SQL in a numeric comparison?

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting

I'm a B-grade SQL user, so bear with me. I have a field that is in the NVARCHAR format ("Year"), but all but only about 1 in 1000 records is something other than a number. Yes, this is a ridiculous way to do this, but we receive this database from a customer, and we can't change it.
I want to pull records from the database where the year field is greater than something (say, 2006 or later). I can ignore any record whose year doesn't evaluate to an actual year. We are using SQL server 2014.
I have created an embedded query to convert the data to a "float" field, but for whatever reason, I can't add a where clause with this new floating-point field. I originally tried using a "case-if" but I got the same result.
I'm pulling my hair out, as I'm either missing something really silly, or there's a bug in SQL server. When I look at the field in the little hint, it's showing as a float. When I run this, I get "Error converting data type nvarchar to float."

```
SELECT VL.Field_A,
  VL.FLYear,
  VL.Field_B
  FROM
    (select
        Field_A,
        cast ([Year] as float) as FLYear,
        /* didn't work either*/
        /*Convert(float, [Year]) as FLYear, */
        Field_B
    from CustomerProvidedDatabaseTable
        where (Field_A like 'E-%' OR
            Field_A  like 'F-%')
        and
            (isnumeric(year)=1)
        and
            year is not null
            ) VL
        /* this statement is the one it chokes on */
    where
        VL.FLYear >= 2006.0
```

If I remove the last "where" clause, it works fine, and the field looks like a number. If I change the last where clause to:

```
 where VL.FLYear like '%2006%'
```

SQL Server accepts it, though of course it doesn't return me all the records I want.

Comment: Edit your question and show samples of what the values look like.

Answer (score 0):

Try to simplify it and just use TRY_CONVERT(DATETIME, aYearvalue) or TRY_PARSE which will return NULL for values it can't convert and continue to process valid rows. I think you can do away with the where clause as join and just work directly against the column like:  (substitute the literal string after datetime with your column)

SET DATEFORMAT mdy;

Select YEAR(try_convert(datetime, '08/01/2017')) as value1
WHERE value1 >=2016;

Answer (score 0):

Try cast/convert to a numeric data type. I have modified the last line of your query to do just that. Take a peek.

```
SELECT 
  VL.Field_A,
  VL.FLYear,
  VL.Field_B
  FROM
    (select
        Field_A,
        cast ([Year] as float) as FLYear,
        /* didn't work either*/
        /*Convert(float, [Year]) as FLYear, */
        Field_B
    from CustomerProvidedDatabaseTable
        where (Field_A like 'E-%' OR
            Field_A  like 'F-%')
        and
            (isnumeric(year)=1)
        and
            year is not null
            ) VL
        /* this statement is the one it chokes on */
    where
        ISNUMERIC(VL.FLYear) = 1
    and 
        CAST(VL.FLYear AS INT) >= 2006
```

> Check out the following link for cast and convert documentation:
>   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql

NOTE: ISNUMERIC will return true ( a false positive for a value which has a scientific numerical value, e.g. 1E10, though I don't see this happening from your data).

Another option is TRY_CONVERT.

> Documentation on TRY_CONVERT: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql

Comment: Eli, this doesn't work. Neither the code you have provided nor the TRY_CONVERT function work. As I said, I'm beginning to think there is a bug in SQL Server 2014.

Comment: Can you recreate this in either SQLFiddle or rextester and share it here?

Answer (score -3):

Try using **Cast** . Use the below link to check in more detail about casting.

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sqlhttps://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql)

Comment: Answers that contain only a link to off-site content are not acceptable here. If you want to post this as an answer, summarize the off-site content here, and then provide the link as an additional reference. The answer should stand on its own if the off-site link is not available for some reason in the future.

Comment: Not that this necessarily changes the problem, but why not cast to an int instead of a float?  If the value is a "year" value, why do you need it decimalized?

Comment: Robert, the records inside the database contain a decimal point.  For example, "2008.00" . I figured it was just easier to cast them to a float.